# detect difference between pausing or leaving an activity vs switching activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, onpause

I have an application with multiple activities and have some behavior in onPause on my MainActivity that I don't want to happen when switching to another activity.

Right now whenever I switch activities the MainActivity onPause() is called and it always runs the behavior.

Comment: Its Activity life Cycle, check this URL https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: I've seen that, but I'm not sure how it answers my question.  It just says both activities life cycles will start.... but nothing about how to determine if the whole app was paused or if just one activity switched to another

Comment: Can you explain what is the behavior?

Comment: When the main activity is paused it deletes a cookie in a webview.... i don't want that cookie to be deleted unless the whole app is paused or stopped, if the user just switches activities i want the cookie to persist

Comment: I think you can use CookieSyncManger , it will help to manage your cookie in application https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the cookie, i just need to figure out how to conditionally delete it based on the app's activity state

Comment: U can change the behaviour call on onDestroy method as it wont be called if u are going to another activity without finishing..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution (a little dirty), you can use a boolean to know when you're switching the activity, set it to `true` just before you call `startActivity(intent)`, and set it to `false` in `onResume()`.

P.S, using `onStop()` is better than `onPause()` in your case, i believe you don't want to delete those cookies when the activity is partially visible

Comment: Where would this variable be stored? Also this solution needs maintain the variable during configuration changes. This solution doesn't scale well when you have several Activitys, and navigating backwards to a previous Activity; especially if the previous activity was destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Activity lifecycles are tightly coordinated, so when launching one Activity B, from Activity A, the following lifecycle events will take place: ActivityA.onPause, ActivityB.onCreate, ActivityB.onStart, ActivityB.onResume, ActivityA.onStop. You can definitely leverage this lifecycle coordination to achieve what you want, if you are move you "behavoir" to the lifecycle method onStop (which is a better place to do most shutdown/stopping work at).

Create a Lifecycle registrar object that will perform the "behavior" when there are no activities are registered in the Lifecycle registrar object. Register your Activities inside of their onStart() and onStop() liefycle callbacks. Inside of the deregister method of your Lifecycle registration object check to see if there are any registered objects and if their aren't you perform you "behavior" whatever that may be. You can extend this functionality to work with Services, just register and deregister the service with the Lifecycle registrar inside the Service's onCreate, onDestroy respectively.

Using onStop instead of onPause, has the added benefit of keeping you from doing your paused/stopped "behavior" when the app is actually in the background and not just partially visibly, such as the case when the system displays a dialog. For example, when requesting to start Bluetooth, the Android OS will generate a dialog prompting the user, and calling onPause. This makes since for some apps but not all apps, and when you think about it, there are a various other use-cases that will cause the app to enter onPause(), that would be annoying to the user for you app to perform shutdown processes.

I have personally utilized this scheme to maintain a open connection, while the app is open and close the connection when the app is killed, or placed in the background. I even modified the Lifecycle Registrar object to maintain the connection during device rotation.